# Resample signal and start from a different point with numpy.interp

Tags: python, interpolation, numpy

I am trying to resample a signal in Python, only by giving the new and the old step. My function works fine until here.
But now I want to start the resampled signal at a specific point other than the initial one, so it will match the points of another signal I have for multiplication.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# DISCLAIMER: This function is copied from https://github.com/nwhitehead/swmixer/blob/master/swmixer.py, 
#             which was released under LGPL. 
def resample_by_interpolation(sig, output_step, input_step, x_range=[0, None] ):

scale = input_step / output_step
# calculate new length of sample
n = round(len(sig) * scale)

# First value (start from)
if None not in x_range: 
    f_init = round(x_range[0] / output_step + 0.5) * output_step
    start = f_init / x_range[1]
else: start, f_init = (0.0, 0)

# using endpoint=False gets less noise in the resampled sound
resampled_sg = np.interp(
    np.linspace(start, 1.0, n, endpoint=False),  # where to interpret
    np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, len(sig), endpoint=False),  # known positions
    sig,  # known data points
)
return resampled_sg, f_init
```

I added this `x_range` and `start` conditions to locate the initial point. The points is found, but the interpolation is messed up, with some displacement. Here is an example with the sinusoidal:

```
x = np.linspace(2, 8*np.pi, 50)
y = np.sin(x)
output_step, input_step = ((x[1]-x[0])/2, x[1]-x[0])
new_y, f_init = resample_by_interpolation(y, output_step, input_step, x_range= [2.5, 25])
new_x = np.linspace(f_init, 25, len(new_y), endpoint=False)


plt.plot(x, y, '--')
plt.plot(new_x, new_y, '-x')
plt.show()
```

The resample should not displace the signal. What I might missing up here?

[image: Resample example with sinusoidal]

**EDIT:**
From @Peter K. suggestion, I made a small change on the code, to start exactly at the desired point:

```
x = np.linspace(2, 25, 50)
y = np.sin(x)
output_step, input_step = ((x[1]-x[0])/2, x[1]-x[0])
new_y = resample_by_interpolation(y, output_step, input_step, x_range= [2.5, 25])
new_x = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), len(new_y))

x_start = 2.5
new_new_x = next(xxx for xxx, val in enumerate(new_x) if val > x_start)

# Find the exactly start point
x1 = [new_x[new_new_x-1], new_x[new_new_x]]
y1 = [new_y[new_new_x-1], new_y[new_new_x]]
y_new = np.interp(x_start, x1, y1)

new_y = resample_by_interpolation([y_new, *new_y[new_new_x:]], output_step, output_step)
new_x = np.linspace(x_start, max(x), len(new_y))

plt.plot(x,y,'--')
plt.plot(new_x, new_y)

plt.show()
```

It is not following the exactly time step though. It goes even worse with `endpoint=False` in `linspace`.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's another attempt.

```
def resample_by_interpolation_with_offset(sig, output_step, input_step, x_start, x_end, x_new_start):
    scale = input_step / output_step
    # calculate new length of sample
    n = round(len(sig) * scale - (x_new_start-x_start)/output_step)
    new_x = np.linspace(x_new_start, x_end, n)

    new_y = np.interp(
        new_x,  # where to interpret
        np.linspace(x_start, x_end, len(sig)),  # known positions
        sig,  # known data points
    )
    return new_x, new_y

x = np.linspace(2, 8*np.pi, 50)
y = np.sin(x)
output_step, input_step = ((x[1]-x[0])/2, x[1]-x[0])
new_x, new_y = resample_by_interpolation_with_offset(y, output_step, input_step, min(x), max(x), 10)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(new_x, new_y, 'x')
plt.show()
```

This yields the following plot.

[image: Third attempt...]

This seems to get `exactly points and time step` that you request.

---

I'm not sure what your copied code is trying to do, but it's not what you want.

The updated code below outputs the two graphs:

This is the original plot (with a change to the line style so we can see both better).

[image: Original]

This is plotting with an $x$-axis of "index" rather than the original $x$ scale, so it can be seen that there are twice the number of points.

[image: Showing that we have double the number of points]

To start at a particular $x$ value (e.g. `x_start`), just do something like:

```
x_start = 2.5
new_new_x = next(xxx for xxx, val in enumerate(new_x) if val > x_start)
plt.plot(x,y,'--')
plt.plot(new_x[new_new_x:], new_y[new_new_x:])
```

after you've done the full interpolation.  This yields something that seems to be what you're after.

[image: Plot of interpolated thing starting somewhere else.]

---

## Original Code Below

```
def resample_by_interpolation(sig, output_step, input_step, x_range=[0, None] ):

    scale = input_step / output_step
    # calculate new length of sample
    n = round(len(sig) * scale)

    resampled_sg = np.interp(
        np.linspace(0, 1.0, n),  # where to interpret
        np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, len(sig)),  # known positions
        sig,  # known data points
    )
    return resampled_sg


x = np.linspace(2, 8*np.pi, 50)
y = np.sin(x)
output_step, input_step = ((x[1]-x[0])/2, x[1]-x[0])
new_y = resample_by_interpolation(y, output_step, input_step, x_range= [2.5, 25])
new_x = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), len(new_y))


plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, y, '--')
plt.plot(new_x, new_y, 'x')
plt.show()

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(new_y)
```

Comment: Ok, that refers to the full resampling of the waveform, not to the start point of resampling. Let's assume that `x = np.linspace(0, 25, 50)`. It goes from 0 to 25 and has 50 points. What if I want the same waveform but with **the starting point of sampling** beginning at t=2.5 and keeping a time step like `output_step` until the end of the waveform? The `x_range` was supposed to give the starting point of the new waveform and a normalization factor (because the function resamples from 0 to 1), but this did not work as I expected...

Comment: @frank.lv ok. Thanks for the explanation. Why can’t you just take the output starting at your required $x$-index?

Comment: that's why. I don't know how to implement that. I tried to find the desired start point with this `start` variable, then interpolating the remaining of the waveform from that point, but it did not work

Comment: @frank.lv OK. I've added a small code snippet that seems to do what you're after. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Tks, we are moving forward, @Peter K., but your suggestion does not start at the desired point _(t=2.5)_, but on the nearest point to it (around 2.697 in this case). I need **exactly** points and time step, so I added an edit that matched the start point, but the time step is still somehow different. Any suggestions for improvement there?